# Pydev Interpreter Problens

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am trying to start a new PyDev project using Eclipse and I am running into an issue finding the Interpreter.

[image: Here is the screen I get for starting a new Project]

It says that the project interpreter is not specified.

[image: When I go to configure the interpreter I am greeted by this screen]

I am not sure where to go from here, did I mess up the installation? 
I have messed around with it and gotten this screen to pop up 
[image: Is there a way I could get the auto-configure to work?]

I believe part of the issue is that the PythonScripts Folder I am making is in my documents while the rest of my eclipse folders are under my User folder. Should I move the Python scripts folder into one of the following folders?

```
eclipse 
eclipse-workspace 
.eclipse
```

Comment: Have you tried manually configuring the interpreter?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I am not sure how to do so. I've looked at the different options but I am scared to mess up something so I came here first.

Comment: I do it that way all the time,. Click "Browse for Python" and it opens a File Explorer Window. Go find PythonXXX.exe and it should work for you.